# Getting multiple checkboxes from FormCollection element

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkbox, formcollection

Given multiple HTML checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="catIDs" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="catIDs" value="2" />
...
<input type="checkbox" name="catIDs" value="100" />
```

How do I retrive an array of integers from a FormCollection in an action:

```
public ActionResult Edit(FormCollection form)
{
    int [] catIDs = (IEnumerable<int>)form["catIDs"]; // ???

    // alternatively:
    foreach (int catID in form["catIDs"] as *SOME CAST*)
    {
        // ...
    }

    return View();
}
```

---

**Note:** I read the related questions and I don't want to change my action parameters, eg. `Edit(int [] catIDs)`.

Comment: You should change the `name` value of the `checkbox`s into `catIds[]`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When you have multiple controls with the same name, they are comma separated values. In other words:

```
string catIDs = form["catIDs"];
```

catIDs is "1,2,3,..."

So to get all the values you would do this:

```
string [] AllStrings = form["catIDs"].Split(',');
foreach(string item in AllStrings)
{
    int value = int.Parse(item);
    // handle value
}
```

Or using Linq:

```
var allvalues = form["catIDs"].Split(',').Select(x=>int.Parse(x));
```

Then you can enumerate through all the values.

Comment: catIDs might be "1,false,3,4,false,6,...". you might have to remove those falses from your list.

Answer (score 17):

The safer way would be to use: `form.GetValues("CatIds")` this will get you the array passed in the post.  Just in case you had commas in your input.